# Summary Listing for Posts or Collections

Tags: jekyll

I read this tutorial for a summary page of posts:
http://schoewilliam.fr/2015/02/10/jekyll-pro-tip-awesome-archive-page.html

It is a page of posts with the display determined by category and clever use of css pseudo properties.

It would be perfect for my site if it worked on pages or collections instead of posts.

I need it to work by category in a collection.

Collection 1

- Category A
- Category B
- Category C
- Category D

OR

A subset of categories for posts:

Group 1

- Category A
  --post 1
  --post 2
- Category B
  --post 1
  --post 2

Group 2

- Category C
  --post 1
  --post 2
- Category D
  --post 1
  --post 2

Can this be done in Jekyll? If anyone knows how or can point to a tutorial written for a beginner, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Instead of categories, you could use Jekyll Collections, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163141/jekyll-pagination-on-multiple-pages/33179651#33179651). For each collection you have a folder, which has it's own markdown files (like "posts"). Then you can call the collection from different sections or pages with liquid markup, it would be up to you how would you like to call them.

Comment: I think I may need to work with nested loops until I get a better feel for how Jekyll works.

Comment: Yeah, it may be a good idea getting used to Jekyll before giving advanced steps... But don't worry, you'll find out that Jekyll is easy and awesome! You'll understand it very quickly! Best of luck :)