# Want to create another _post directory in jekyll

Tags: post, jekyll, podcast

I want to create a author `_layout` that I could use to mount a list of all the author of a Jekyll powered site (in fact, a list of hosts of a podcast). I want this to be at

```
+ \
  + _posts
  + _includes
  + _layouts
  + _config.yml
  + authors <-- Here
```

In my Jekyll site, and I already saw that Jekyll render markdown files there.

However, I can't take the authors there and use it to build a list.

I'm using this code

```
<ul>
    {% for post in site.categories.authors %}
    <li><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Any suggestion on how I should do what I want? I want the page to be generate to return the name of the hosts in a list, with links for each of them, like

```
<a href="/authors/foo">This guy</a>
<a href="/authors/bar">That guy</a>
<a href="/authors/baz">That other guy</a>
```

And the files to be rendered being at:

```
+ \
  + _posts
  + _includes
  + _layouts
  + _config.yml
  + authors
    + foo.md
    + bar.md
    + baz.md
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use collections, you will need to configure them properly. But collections is useful when you need to add extra markdown files and you don't want them in `_posts`.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163141/jekyll-pagination-on-multiple-pages/33179651#33179651) if you want to go for collections.

---

But what I believe what you need is [Jekyll `_data`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/), not collections.

To do so, create a folder called `_data` in the site `root` and add file called `authors.yml` into that.

Then, you add to `authors.yml` the data you want to call:

```
- ref: 01
  name: Name Surname
  url: http://something.com

- ref: 02
  name: Name Surname 2
  url: http://somethingelse.com
```

Then call them via liquid:

```
{% for author in site.data.authors %}
<a href="{{ author.url }}">{{ author.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question.... I really hope to have helped!